# Laravel permission cache

Tags: laravel

I am using my own implementation for user roles and permissions in laravel how to cache all the permissions and roles on user login and also to refresh the cache when new record is added.
My tables are users ,roles, permissions,permission_role,permission_user,role_user.  This is my table structure

i have created on of the provider and added this code to boot method

```
Permission::get()->map(function ($permission) 
            {
                Gate::define($permission->name, function ($user) use ($permission) 
                {
                    return $user->hasPermission($permission);
                });
            });
```

it is working fine but it is running the query each time which gets slowing down my application is there any way to cache all the permissions

here is my PermissionServiceProvider class

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
use App\Models\Permission;

class PermissionServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        if (Schema::hasTable('permissions'))
         {
            Permission::get()->map(function ($permission) 
            {
                Gate::define($permission->name, function ($user) use ($permission) 
                {
                    return $user->hasPermission($permission);
                });
            });
        }

        Blade::directive('role', function ($role)
            {
               return "<?php if(Auth::user()->hasRole({$role})): ?>";
            });
        Blade::directive('endrole', function ($role)
            {
                return "<?php endif; ?>";
            });
    }

    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

and finally inside the user  model

```
public function hasPermission($permission)
    {
        return $this->hasPermissionThroughRole($permission) || (bool) $this->permissions->where('name',$permission->name)->count();
    }

    public function hasPermissionThroughRole($permission)
    {
        foreach($permission->roles as $role)
        {
            if($this->roles->contains($role))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

and also here is my bit bucket repo

https://manojkiran@bitbucket.org/manojkiran/userrolesandpermissions.git

i have tried the method of `@emtiaz-zahid`  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53511803/8487424 its working fine to cache all the `permisisons` in `permissions` table but is there any way to cahe all the permisisons and also the permissions to specifc user and role of the currently logged in user

Comment: *how to cache all the permissions and roles on user login and also to refresh the cache when new record is added.* there are few approaches: 1) just cache it in session or cookie, 2) cache it using [laravel cache](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/cache) feature and purge the cache whenever update is done

Comment: First elaborate your question with some code if available.

Comment: here is my complete code [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53718686/8487424)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Laravel model cache like shown in the following link:

https://laravel-news.com/laravel-model-caching

I would create a method for getting and caching the current users roles and permissions.

You can read more about Caching here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/cache

I hope this helps

**Update**

Try something like this

```
if (Schema::hasTable('permissions') ) {

    $userId = Auth::user()->id

    return Cache::remember($this->cacheKey() . $userId . ':permissions', 60, function() use ($userId) {

       return Permission::where('user_id', $userId)->get();

    }

}
```

Then you just need to update your `hasPermission()` method to check the cache.

Also try to avoid `map()` as php takes a lot longer than sql

Comment: I have updated my answer with example of the code to use!

Comment: i have tried it but i am getting error [see here](https://ibb.co/KKyvsZZ)

Comment: You have forgotten the ; after setting the userId

Answer (score 0):

You can store your cache in service provider. I just sharing my method

```
$permissions = Cache::rememberForever('permissions', function () {
                    return Permission::get();
                 });
```

this will remember permissions with key name `permissions` forever until you change it

you can also remember this with specific time

```
 $permissions = Cache::remember('permissions', 3600, function () {
                        return Permission::get();
                     });
```

I placed it in app service provider so that every time on app load it check if `permissions` found in cache then don't run the query and if not found then take it from DB

so your script could be like this after the cache part:

```
$permissions->map(function ($permission) 
            {
                Gate::define($permission->name, function ($user) use ($permission) 
                {
                    return $user->hasPermission($permission);
                });
            });
```

find more on [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/cache)

Comment: Hi Emitaz. That will get all permission but not the permissions for the current user

Comment: I just shared the concept of store data in cache and then use it later, you can check if the current user permissions exists in $permissions array or not.

Comment: now i have tried it it is caching all the permission available in the permissions table

Comment: but is there any way to cache all the permissions and also the permission to specific user or roles who is currently loggging in

Comment: currently logged user data can be found in Auth::user() , and its all data are stored in session, so every time when you need to get any data from user table it does not execute another query.

Answer (score 0):

finally I found the solution.
Artisan cache clear command is not working well.
Try to remove the cache on this folder.
storage/framework/cache/data

This should work for sure.
Good luck